# Problem Installing Network Simulator 2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, gcc, ns2

A university course on Computer Networks requires to have Network Simulator 2 installed. But I struggle a lot to make this install happen.

## What I Have Done So Far

- Have downloaded the ns2 binaries from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsnam/files/allinone/ns-allinone-2.35/)
- Have executed these commands (basically installing the dependences needed)

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

- Have executed these commands to install the software

```
tar xvfzns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35
sudo ./install
```

## The Problem

The compilation goes fine until this point:

```
mdart/mdart_adp.cc: In member function ‘void ADP::sendDarq(nsaddr_t, int)’:
mdart/mdart_adp.cc:108:21: error: reference to ‘hash’ is ambiguous
  nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(reqId);
                     ^~~~
In file included from ./mdart/mdart.h:52:0,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
./mdart/mdart_function.h:230:17: note: candidates are: nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t)
 inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6587:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bitset:47,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_function.h:62,
                 from ./mdart/mdart.h:52,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: note:                 template<class _Tp> struct std::hash
     struct hash;
            ^~~~
mdart/mdart_adp.cc: In member function ‘void ADP::sendDaup()’:
mdart/mdart_adp.cc:396:21: error: reference to ‘hash’ is ambiguous
  nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(mdart_->id_);
                     ^~~~
In file included from ./mdart/mdart.h:52:0,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
./mdart/mdart_function.h:230:17: note: candidates are: nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t)
 inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6587:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bitset:47,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_function.h:62,
                 from ./mdart/mdart.h:52,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: note:                 template<class _Tp> struct std::hash
     struct hash;
            ^~~~
Makefile:93: recipe for target 'mdart/mdart_adp.o' failed
make: *** [mdart/mdart_adp.o] Error 1
Ns make failed!
See http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html for problems
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193831/installing-network-simulator-2-on-manjaro-system/48196189#comment112594664_48196189) question on Stack Overflow, I tried the proposed solution but that didn't work for me. Can someone guide me on what should I do ? I give exams in a week and it's an emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04, simply do : `sudo apt install g++-4.8`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=g%2B%2B-4.8&searchon=names ... Please note that you can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time. Other examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Build ns-2.35 :

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz    (2014 update)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
```

Comment: Same error happened. Did everything exactly as you instructed.

Comment: Well, you can have an infinite number of installed ns2, so please just unpack a new ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz in a new folder and repeat the one liner command (export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install) till you succeed https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing